# On using srun or salloc to launch interactive sessions

Tags: slurm

I have a fair amount of hands-on experience with LSF, and this is actually interfering with my learning of SLURM.

I am particularly confused by `srun` and `salloc`, since I cannot map them to any of the LSF commands I am familiar with.

Most of all, I am puzzled by the fact that I have come across several "recipes" for starting an interactive session, some of which use `srun` for this, while the other ones use `salloc`.

For example, in the system I have access to, SLURM is configured so that *either one* of the following two commands would start an interactive shell session for me:

```
$ srun   --mem=$MEMORY --pty -- $SHELL
$ salloc --mem=$MEMORY
```

What exactly is the relationship between `srun` and `salloc`?  Is `salloc` a special case of `srun`?

Answer (score 4):

The `srun` command was initially designed to start a parallel program on the resources allocated the job, you can think of it as a Slurm-provided `mpirun`. The idea was that if you want a batch job, you create a submission script in which you use the `srun` command to start the program, and submit that job with `sbatch`. If you want an interative job, you rather run `salloc`, then, when the resources are allocated, you run `srun` whithin that allocation, in an interactive way. The `salloc` command only requests resources and updates the environment with the SLURM variables. At that time, `salloc` would "leave you" on the login node and you had to run `srun` to obtain a shell on a compute node.

For debugging, if often happens that what users need is simply a Bash session on a single compute node. Or they need to run multiple short-lived parallel jobs. In both cases, running `salloc` then `srun` can be seen as a loss of time. Therefore, very early on, `srun` was given the ablilty to request an allocation if it is not run within one. Since then, the recommendation for obtaining an interactive Bash session on a compute node was to run `srun ... --pty -- $SHELL`. But that only worked for single-node jobs, prevented to further run `srun` within that interactive job (to start an MPI program for instance), and led to confusion in the mind of many users.

Since version 20.11, the `InteractiveStepOptions` defines the behaviour of `salloc` when launched. By default, now, with `LaunchParameters=use_interactive_step` it runs `srun` so that a shell is started on the first node of the allocation. This works both for single-node jobs as for multi-node jobs. The new recommendation for an interactive job with the default configuration, is therefore now to run `salloc ...`, covering most usecases properly, and simplifing the situation.

Now the situation is a bit clearer:

- To request an allocation, either

  - submit a batch job: `sbatch`; or
  - start an interactive job: `salloc`
- Within that job allocation:

  - you can start a parallel program with `srun`
  - you can copy files to the compute nodes with `sbcast`

Comment: That seems more detailed than [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77869242/6309). Upvoted.

Comment: I see. What a pity that not all systems are configured the same way. Our cluster runs version 20.11.8 and its default configuration do not match the one you said :-(
Also, the wording of the `salloc` man page leads to confusion, as it seems to imply that the command executed runs on the allocation just created but, as you said, the command run on the login node and you have to send it to the compute node explicitly with `srun`. SLURM developers, take a look at the docs! :-)

Comment: For other readers: MPI stands for [Message Passing Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Passing_Interface). It is a standardized and portable message-passing system designed to function on a wide variety of parallel computing architectures. MPI is commonly used in high-performance computing (HPC) to enable processes to communicate with each other by sending and receiving messages, important for distributed computing and parallel execution of programs, especially in cluster environments.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`srun` man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html) (v23.11), `srun` is used to run parallel jobs on a cluster managed by [SLURM (Simple Linux Utility for Resource Management)](https://slurm.schedmd.com/quickstart.html).
It can create a resource allocation if necessary to run the job.
The command `srun --mem=$MEMORY --pty -- $SHELL`, as mentioned in your example, starts an interactive shell session as a job. The `--pty` flag allocates a pseudo-terminal, important for interactive sessions, and `$SHELL` invokes the user's default shell.

From the [`salloc` man page](https://slurm.schedmd.com/salloc.html) (v23.11), `salloc` is used to allocate resources for a job, and it can immediately execute a command within those allocated resources.
If a command is provided to `salloc`, it will run that command after allocating the necessary resources.
If no command is specified, `salloc` allocates the resources and returns control to the user's command line, effectively creating an environment for any subsequent commands the user wishes to run within the allocated resources.

So `salloc` can be used in two ways:

- **with a command**: It allocates resources and immediately runs the specified command within those resources.
- **without a command**: It allocates resources and returns to the command line, allowing the user to manually execute commands within the allocated environment.

`salloc` is not a special case of `srun`; rather, they are used together to manage different aspects of job handling and resource allocation in a SLURM environment.

- You can use `salloc` to allocate resources, and then within that allocation, use `srun` to execute specific commands or jobs.
- Alternatively, `srun` can be used independently to both allocate resources and execute a command in one step.

---

In both cases, they could be compared to the [`bsub` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=SSWRJV_10.1.0%2Flsf_command_ref%2Fbsub.man_top.1.htm) of the "[IBM Spectrum LSF (Load Sharing Facility)](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spectrum-lsf/10.1.0?topic=overview-lsf-introduction)" job scheduler.

`srun` is used to execute a job or command directly on allocated resources. It can initiate a new job allocation if none exists, or run within an existing allocation.
`bsub` in LSF is first used for submitting a job to the batch system. It schedules and manages the job based on resource availability and system policies.
Comparison: Both `srun` and `bsub` are used for job execution, but `srun` offers more immediate execution and is often used for interactive sessions or one-off tasks.

`salloc` is used for allocating resources for a job, either for immediate or future use. After allocation, you can run `srun` within this allocation to execute specific tasks.
`bsub`, similar to `salloc`, is used for job submission with resource requests. However, `bsub` is more focused on scheduling and queuing jobs for batch processing.
Comparison: Both `salloc` and `bsub` deal with resource allocation, but `salloc` is more about creating an environment for subsequent commands, whereas `bsub` is about submitting and scheduling jobs.

---

**Workflow Summary**

- For batch jobs: use `sbatch` to submit the job.
- For interactive jobs: use `salloc`, which now implicitly starts a shell on the allocated resources.
  As noted in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77855517/on-using-srun-or-salloc-to-launch-interactive-sessions/77869242#comment137283070_77869242) by [Poshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3000629/poshi), it is not the case prior to 20.11 version.
- Within an allocation (either from `sbatch` or `salloc`): use `srun` to start parallel programs or perform specific tasks.

```bash
+----------------+           +-----------------+          +------------------+
|     sbatch     |           |     salloc      |          |       srun       |
| (Submit Batch  |           | (Start          |          | (Execute Parallel|
|  Job)          |           | Interactive Job)|          |  Program/Tasks)  |
+----------------+           +-----------------+          +------------------+
        |                             |                            |
        |  Submit Job                 |  Request Resources &       |
        |                             |  Start Shell on First Node |
        +---------------------------> +--------------------------->+
        |                             |                            |
        |                             |  Use srun for Parallel     |
        |                             |  Programs/Tasks within     |
        |                             |  the Allocation            |
        +--------------------------------------------------------->+
```

Comment: It's still hard to me to spot the difference. Conceptually, they do different things: allocate resources or run commands. In practice, `salloc` allocate resources and can execute commands on them while `srun` execute commands and allocate resources if needed. Seems to be interchangeable.

Comment: And yet, they work differently. A few days ago I tried a `salloc ... hostname` and the result was the hostname of the current node, not the allocated one. If `salloc` is supposed to "allocate resources for a job, and it can immediately execute a command within those allocated resources", what happened? The `hostname` command apparently was not executed in those allocated resources, but on the current node.

Comment: @Poshi I have edited the answer to clarify the workflow. [Damien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77871658/6309) has more details.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but according to Damien's answer, *in my case* that is wrong too. You say that "salloc, which now implicitly starts a shell on the allocated resources", but the reality is that your shell is still on the login node, not the allocated compute node. But this only happens in my SLURM configuration and on old configurations (prior to 20.11 version).
So, for future readers, this answer only considers default configurations of the most recent SLURM versions.

Comment: @Poshi So I need to add post 20.11 to my description?

Comment: Well, it would help users know why the behavior of their systems does not match the one described in your answer. It is not that your answer is incorrect, but only valid for a subset of installations.

Comment: @Poshi OK, thank you for that feedback. I have edited the answer to make the version clearer.